# Where can I find the latest WMX (JTX) Object Model Diagrams for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'm looking for a version that includes ESRI.ArcGIS.JTXUI--I'm hoping someone knows of an updated and online version of `C:\Program Files\WMX\Developer Kit\Diagrams\ObjectModel.pdf`.

For reference, I'm on ArcGIS 10 SP2:

- ObjectModel.pdf is dated: 10/27/2010
- SDK.chm is dated 6/4/2010

*So these weren't updated by either service pack.*

Comment: So if the OMD's weren't updated, maybe the things they discuss were not updated?  Service Packs are meant to fix problems, not add new functionality.

Comment: I'm not looking for updated functionality.  I'm looking for updated documentation (Esri did say the WMX docs/code samples might be refreshed at a later service pack...was hoping SP2 might be the lucky service pack).